# How to call a function in an if statement and at the same time store its return code?

Tags: bash, shell

Apparently, the exit states `$?` that get assigned to the specified return codes in the code below do not come from the `uno`, `dos`, `tres` commands. How to get it right?

I have to run over the three commands several times, because I do not want to execute `dos` and/or `tres` if `uno` fails, and `tres` if `uno` or `dos` fails  - I start over again. In other words: *it makes no sense to continue if the first one/ones fail.*

*There are more than 3 function calls in the real program, in fact, there are 7 function calls; the snippet was simplified a bit.*

```
local return_code=1
while (("${passed_time_in_seconds}" <= "${seconds_to_wait_for}")); do
      if uno; uno_return_code=$? \
        && dos; dos_return_code=$? \
        && tres; tres_return_code=$?; then
          return_code=0
          break
      else
        sleep "${seconds_to_sleep}"
        current_time_in_seconds=$(date +%s)
        passed_time_in_seconds=$(get_passed_time_in_seconds "${start_time_in_seconds}" "${current_time_in_seconds}")
       fi
done

if [[ return_code -ne 0 ]]; then
  do some checks on uno_return_code, dos_return_code, tres_return_code 
fi
```

Comment: `&&` has higher precedence than `;`, so `cmda; a=$? && cmdb; b=$?` is treated as `cmda` followed by the compound command `a=$? && cmdb` (which will always run `cmdb`, because the `a=$?` command will always succeed), followed by `b=$?`. So what you have now doesn't do anything like what you want.

Comment: If don't reach the line with ```return_code=0```, I left the while-loop because of the timeout. When that happens, I want to check which commands were failing... by checking the stored return_codes.

Comment: Why not just do `if uno && dos && tres; return 0; fi` ?

Comment: Because, in case the functions do not succeed within the time limit, I have to look closer at the failed functions, hence I need to know which ones were failing. Some of them I can try to fix, others not.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, thank you for the hint. I have found this documentation concerning the precedence in bash
https://www.aquaclusters.com/app/home/project/public/Advanced-Bash-Scripting-Guide-1/wikibook/Advanced-Bash-Scripting-Guide/page/8.4.-Operator-Precedence/8-4-Operator-Precedence

Comment: @Ina I would not rely on that guide. Shell syntax is very context-dependent, and that table mixes together the operators for arithmetic contexts with those from `[ ]` test expressions. For example, it says `=` is assigment and `==` is equality test, which is correct in arithmetic syntax, but in a `[ ]` test `=` is string equality and `==` is nonstandard. In any case, the table doesn't apply at all to the connectives between commands (e.g. between commands, `|` is a pipe, not a bitwise OR).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a good demo of a solution I made functions `uno()` `dos()` and `tres()` that will fail 3 times with different returncodes and than succeed.
I removed all sleep/date stuff, that is not essential for your question.

```
#!/bin/bash
uno() {
  echo "Executed uno"
  ((i++))
  ((i>3)) || return $i
}

dos() {
  echo "Executed dos"
  ((j++))
  ((j>3)) || return $j
}

tres() {
  echo "Executed tres"
  ((k++))
  ((k>3)) || return $k
}

i=0
j=0
k=0
for ((n=0;n<12;n++)); do
  lastf=uno  && uno  &&
  lastf=dos  && dos  &&
  lastf=tres && tres
  echo "Function ${lastf} returned $?"
  echo "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz Something with sleep zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
done
```

Comment: that is an interesting idea. I will test it tomorrow. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The exit status of a list of commands is the exit status the last command executed.

Exit status of an assignment (without any command substitutions) is always 0.

```
  if 
       uno
       uno_return_code=$? && dos;
       dos_return_code=$? && tres;

       tres_return_code=$? 
      # ^^^^^^ last command executed, only it matters for `if`
      # exit status of assignment is always 0
      # 0 means success
  then
       : this will always execute
  fi
```

Instead check them.

Also, when checking timeout, it's easier (and safer) to check against end, then to calculate difference each time.

```
return_code=1
# on bash use we can use (EPOCH-)SECONDS instead of date +%s!
end=$((SECONDS + seconds_to_wait_for))
while ((SECONDS < end)); do
   uno
   uno_return_code=$?
   dos
   dos_return_code=$?
   tres
   tres_return_code=$?
  
   if ((uno_return_code == 0 && dos_return_code == 0 &&
            tres_return_code == 0)); then
       return_code=0
       break
   fi
done

if (( !return_code )); then
    : something

fi
```

Maybe you meant to "only execute dos when uno succeeded". I would do it verbose and explicitly, like:

```
    uno
    uno_return_code=$?
    if ((!uno_return_code)); then
         dos
         dos_return_code=$?
         if ((!dos_return_code)); then
            tres
            tres_return_code=$?
            if ((!tres_return_code)); then
                break
            fi
        fi
    fi
```

Or it may look nicer with `continue`:

```
   uno
   uno_return_code=$?
   if ((uno_return_code)); then continue; fi
   dos
   dos_return_code=$?
   if ((!dos_return_code)); then continue; fi
   tres
   tres_return_code=$?
   if ((!tres_return_code)); then continue; fi
   break
```

Overall, I like swapping checking timeout and condition. You are waiting for commands, not for timeout. This also takes care that if the timeout is zero, the condition will still execute once.

```
while
    uno
    uno_return_code=$?
    if ((!uno_return_code)); then
         dos
         dos_return_code=$?
         if ((!dos_return_code)); then
            tres
            tres_return_code=$?
        fi
    fi
   (( uno_return_code != 0 || dos_return_code != 0 ||
            tres_return_code != 0 ))
do
   if ((SECONDS > end)); do
       break;
   done
   sleep "${seconds_to_sleep}"
done
```

Comment: In bash v5.0+, we can use the builtin `$EPOCHSECONDS` instead of calling out to date. Or, in this case, since we're just counting a duration, use the builtin `$SECONDS`

Comment: Comment to the second code block: 
I have tried this method already. The problem with it is that I run through ```uno```, ```dos```, and ```tres``` even though it makes no sense to continue if the first one/ones fail.

Comment: `it makes no sense to continue if the first one/ones fail.` _then write that condition_. See the other couple of edits.

Comment: I have to run over the three commands several times, because I do not want to execute dos and/or tres if uno fails, and tres if uno or dos fails  - I start over again. ```In other words: it makes no sense to continue if the first one/ones fail.```

I added the sentence. I guess the sentence before it was not clear enough.

Comment: @KamilCuk, thank you for your reply. I appreciate it a lot.
I will consider your fourth suggestion.. The problem with the third code block is that it is not clean code.

Comment: The fifth code block is also not a clean code -- with the increasing number of function calls it will be difficult to read. But thanks anyway.

Comment: "Clean" is subjective. If you want more functions, write abstractions for that. Taking a list of functions to call and calling them in order seems like a simple loop.

Comment: I try to stick to the "subjectivity" of Robert C. Martin concerning Clean Code.